# Wrong apk gets downloaded in Multiple apk scenario in android

Tags: android, android-screen-support, android-multiple-apk

I have shipped an android application on Playstore with multiple apks.In one apk's manifest I have defined this-

```
<supports-screens 
              android:smallScreens="true"
              android:normalScreens="true"
              android:largeScreens="true"
              android:xlargeScreens="true"
```

with versionCode 3.

In other apk's manifest which support large and xlarge devices I have defined this -

```
<supports-screens 
              android:smallScreens="false"
              android:normalScreens="false"
              android:largeScreens="true"
              android:xlargeScreens="true"
              android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
```

with versionCode 1001.

But when I install my application from Playstore on MotoG which is supposedly a normal size device,it installs the second apk.I can confirm this by that in my first apk I have disabled orientation changes but in my second apk I have allowed both portrait and landscape for large and xlarge devices.

Why is MotoG(a normal size device) downloading an apk meant fot large and xlarge devices?Have I done something wrong or I can rectify it? Supported SDK versions in my app are 3.2 onwards.